# SparkR Error while writing dataframe to csv and parquet

Tags: rstudio, sparkr

I'm getting error while writing spark dataframe to csv and parquet. I already try to install winutil but still not solving the error.

my code

```
    INVALID_IMEI <- c("012345678901230","000000000000000")
    setwd("D:/Revas/Jatim Old")
    fileList <- list.files()
    cdrSchema <- structType(structField("date","string"),
                      structField("time","string"),
                      structField("a_number","string"),
                      structField("b_number", "string"),
                      structField("duration","integer"),
                      structField("lac_cid","string"),
                      structField("imei","string"))
    file <- fileList[1]
    filePath <- paste0("D:/Revas/Jatim Old/",file)
    dataset <- read.df(filePath, header="false",source="csv",delimiter="|",schema=cdrSchema)
    dataset <- filter(dataset, ifelse(dataset$imei %in% INVALID_IMEI,FALSE,TRUE))
    dataset <- filter(dataset, ifelse(isnan(dataset$imei),FALSE,TRUE))
    dataset <- filter(dataset, ifelse(isNull(dataset$imei),FALSE,TRUE))
```

To export the dataframe, i try the following code

```
    write.df(dataset, "D:/spark/dataset",mode="overwrite")
    write.parquet(dataset, "D:/spark/dataset",mode="overwrite")
```

And i get the following error

```
Error: Error in save : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.comma
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the possible cause. The issue seem to lie in the winutil version, previously im using 2.6. Changing it to 2.8 seem to solve the issue